# Drawing transparent sprites in a 3D world in OpenGL(LWJGL)

Tags: sorting, opengl, 3d, transparency, sprite

I need to draw transparent 2D sprites in a 3D world. I tried rendering a QUAD, texturing it(using slick_util) and rotating it to face the camera, but when there are many of them the transparency doesn't really work. The sprite closest to the camera will block the ones behind it if it's rendered before them.

I think it's because OpenGL only draws the object that is closest to the viewer without checking the alpha value. 
This could be fixed by sorting them from furthest away to closest but I don't know how to do that
and wouldn't I have to use math.sqrt to get the distance? (I've heard it's slow)

I wonder if there's an easy way of getting transparency in 3D to work correctly. (Enabling something in OpenGL e.g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable depth testing and render transparent geometry back to front.

Or switch to additive blending and hope that looks OK.

Or use [depth peeling](https://developer.nvidia.com/system/files/akamai/gamedev/docs/order_independent_transparency.pdf).

Comment: I will try additive blending. I haven't seen depth peeling before, it looked complicated